# Proving $\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a^3}{a^2+8b^2}}\ge\sqrt{\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$ for positive $a$, $b$, $c$

Tags: inequality

Hard problem with inequalities:

> Let $a,b,c>0.$ Prove that
> $$\sqrt{\dfrac{a^3}{a^2+8b^2}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{b^3}{b^2+8c^2}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{c^3}{c^2+8a^2}} \ge \sqrt{\dfrac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$

I saw it's on AOPS [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h2245438p17253377).

I just can prove the weaker problem, it's
$$\sqrt{\dfrac{a^3}{a^2+8b^2}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{b^3}{b^2+8c^2}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{c^3}{c^2+8a^2}} \ge \sqrt{\dfrac{a+b+c}{3}}.$$
Assume that $a+b+c=3.$ And By AM-GM
$$9a+a^2+8b^2 \ge 6\sqrt{a(a^2+8b^2)},$$
or
$$\sqrt{\dfrac{a^3}{a^2+8b^2}} \ge \dfrac{6a^2}{9a+a^2+8b^2}.$$
So
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\dfrac{a^3}{a^2+8b^2}} \ge \sum\limits_{cyc}\dfrac{6a^2}{9a+a^2+8b^2}.$$
And by Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\dfrac{6a^2}{9a+a^2+8b^2} \ge \dfrac{6(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{a^4+b^4+c^4+9(a^3+b^3+c^3)+8(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)} \ge 1,$$
which the last inequality is easy.
I hope holder can kill it, but I can't find something :(
This is the first time I have asked a problem. If there are something wrong, I will improve.

Comment: I don't have proof for it. I hope to see some nice proof.

Comment: @NguyễnTháiAn Being a bit too rash here, are you not?

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I have written my question on this forum. I will improve in my next ask.

Comment: You can edit your question to include your thoughts.

Comment: @Soumik Mukherjee Are you sure that he'll have time before this topic would be  deleted?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I thought maybe the OP could save the question in time.

Comment: Please provide context for this question, give us for instance the source, the level, the year, the country, the publication... when it appeared, and moreover, a must on this site, please show us the own tries and where you got stuck. Please take a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question to see what is needed to have a question. Next ask is too late. Else, this question is lost, will get downvotes, and will be closed soon with a high probability, few votes are needed only. This is frustrating, and also a missed chance to "sell" a good problem.

Comment: Thank you all. I edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Holder $$\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\tfrac{a^3}{a^2+8b^2}}=\sqrt{\tfrac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\tfrac{a^3}{a^2+8b^2}}\right)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+8b^2)(c^2+ca+2a^2)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+8b^2)(c^2+ca+2a^2)^3}}\geq\sqrt{\tfrac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^3+a^2b+a^2c)\right)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+8b^2)(c^2+ca+2a^2)^3}}$$ and it's enough to prove that
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^3+a^2b+a^2c)\right)^3\geq(a^3+b^3+c^3)\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+8b^2)(c^2+ca+2a^2)^3$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(12a^{10}b-39a^9b^2+38a^8b^3+28a^8c^3+42a^7b^4+30a^7c^4-8a^6b^5+41a^6c^5)+$$
$$+abc\sum_{cyc}(12a^8-57a^7b+15a^7c+42a^6b^2+54a^6c^2+57a^5b^3+57a^5c^3-36a^4b^4)+$$
$$+a^2b^2c^2\sum_{cyc}(-138a^5-9a^4b-48a^4c-108a^3b^2-180a^3c^2+60a^3bc+135a^2b^2c)\geq0,$$ which is true by BW.

Comment: Thanks. 
I think the last step is really ugly, but it's true.
Do you think BW will end it?

Comment: @Nguyễn Thái An I proved it by hand. I am ready to show.

Comment: Really? If so, it will be interesting to me.

Comment: What a very nice Solution! 
Thank you very much, @Michael Rozenberg.

Comment: @Nguyễn Thái An I have found a mistake in my proof by hand. I am sorry. We can prove it by BW. It's really trivial  by using this way.

Comment: Similar problem, see below: https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=10229634902673784&set=a.2302153830218

Comment: @Trần Nk Trang I think the linked problem is easier.